# Дефис или раздельно?

Tags: грамматика

`"Цель минимум"` или `"цель-минимум"`?

Answer (score 1):

Данное сочетание слов пишется через дефис: *цель-минимум*. Слово *минимум* является однословным приложением, следующим за определяемым словом. Подробнее см у Лопатина в Правилах русской орфографии и пунктуации, § 120)

Answer (score 0):

Корректно через дефис. Ср. Программа-минимум.